# strange behaviour of OCaml when writing a function in two different ways

Tags: types, ocaml

I have the following code (which works) :

```
type a = A of int
let print = ref (fun _ -> ())
let f x = !print (A x)
```

But the following doesn't work :

```
let print = ref (fun _ -> ())
type a = A of int
let f x = !print (A x)
```

I am wondering why exchanging two lines causes the code to be invalid.

Thank you !

EDIT : when running the second code I get the following error  :

```
Error: This expression has type a but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type constructor a would escape its scope
```

Comment: You didn't only exchange the lines, you also capitalized the type name and I think that may be why you are experiencing problems

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you get

Comment: @Carcigenicate when I run the code it doesn't work. See my edit

Comment: @smac89 Yes I am sorry. See my edit.

Answer (score 8):

In brief, the type of a reference must be defined before the reference is created:
you should be able to annotate the type of `print` when your first define it.
And by exchanging the definition of `a` and `print`, you made this last point impossible:

```
  let print: ( ??? -> unit) ref  = ref (fun _ -> ())
  type a = A of int
```

Here, the `???` should be `a` but the type `a` is yet to be defined.

More precisely, types in OCaml have a scope in order to detect when a local type would escape the context where it is defined and meaningful. For instance

```
let x =
  let module M = struct type t = A end in
  M.A
```

fails with the same error as your second example

> Error: This expression has type M.t but an expression was expected of type 'a
>          The type constructor M.t would escape its scope

Here, letting the type `M.t` escape the body of the definition of `x` would be bad because the module `M` and thus the type `M.t` is not defined outside of this definition.

Your example fails for a similar reason. The variable

```
let print = ref (fun _ -> ())
```

has type `('_weak1 -> unit) ref` where `'_weak1` is a placeholder type for a still unknown type. But the future type of the reference should already exists at this point.

Thus, when you define the new type

```
type t = A of int
```

and try to assign this type to the `'_weak1` weak type variable,

```
let print': (t -> unit) ref = print
```

the typechecker complains that the type `t` was undefined when the type variable `'_weak1` was created:

> Error: This expression has type ('weak1 -> unit) ref
>          but an expression was expected of type (t -> unit) ref
>          The type constructor t would escape its scope

Similarly, your function `f`

```
 let f x = !print (A x)
```

implies that the type of `!print` would be `t -> unit` and lead to a similar error:

> Error: This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type 'weak1
>          The type constructor t would escape its scope